# Timer - Count up timer for Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, user-interface, timer, angular-directive

I am trying to display a timer as shown below in this screenshot. To count up constantly to show how long since this entry has been made.

[image]

I couldn't find too many options for doing it in Angular. I found this solution in Angular JS. https://siddii.github.io/angular-timer/ I need the timer exactly like this. But I was not able to port it into Angular or I couldn't. So tried the other alternatives available and found these still they are all also not working.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-simple-timer

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-timer

The closest I got to was this ngx-timer's Countup-timer.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-timer the timer works fine and its able to start from a given date as per my requirement. startTimer(startDate). But it has an known issue which is still unresolved that is it applies itself to the last known index of the timer element thereby only one timer running in a whole list of timers.You can notice that in the above given screenshot itself.

its a known bug. https://github.com/Y4SHVINE/ngx-timer-lib/issues

So can somebody help me with a solution or some tweaks to one of these solutions to make it work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would do this by writing a function to return the difference between the current time and the creation time of an object.

My initial thought was to return the difference as a `Date` object and then format the result. I soon ran into problems when formatting different time spans, as a date is not the same thing as a time span.

So instead of trying to format a `Date` that is pretending to be a time span, I would create my own interface.

```js
export interface TimeSpan {
  hours: number;
  minutes: number;
  seconds: number;
}
```

By doing this we retain control of how time spans >= 1 day are handled, and avoid time zone issues.

I would use `OnPush` change detection to keep control over when change detection is run:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private changeDetector: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
}
```

I would then kick off an RxJS `interval` in `ngOnInit()`, making sure to unsubscribe when we're finished:

```js
private destroyed$ = new Subject();

ngOnInit() {
  interval(1000).subscribe(() => {
    this.changeDetector.detectChanges();
  });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.destroyed$.next();
  this.destroyed$.complete();
}
```

The HTML would then get the elapsed time from a function on my component:

```js
getElapsedTime(entry: Entry): TimeSpan {        
  let totalSeconds = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - entry.created.getTime()) / 1000);

  let hours = 0;
  let minutes = 0;
  let seconds = 0;

  if (totalSeconds >= 3600) {
    hours = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 3600);      
    totalSeconds -= 3600 * hours;      
  }

  if (totalSeconds >= 60) {
    minutes = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
    totalSeconds -= 60 * minutes;
  }

  seconds = totalSeconds;

  return {
    hours: hours,
    minutes: minutes,
    seconds: seconds
  };
}
```

This function starts off by getting the total number of seconds elapsed since the creation date, and then works out the hour, minute, and second components.

Where `entry` is the object that contains some `Date` instance indicating its creation time. For my demo, I am using this interface:

```js
export interface Entry {
  created: Date;
  id: string;
}
```

The elapsed time span can then be retrieved for each instance inside an `*ngFor` like this:

```html
<span *ngIf="getElapsedTime(entry) as elapsed">
  {{elapsed.hours}} h {{elapsed.minutes}} m {{elapsed.seconds}} s
</span>
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p1b9af

Comment: Thank you , it works like a charm !! the perfect implementation. I was able to integrate it with my code without any issues. Only thing was i had to pass the date into the `getElapsedTime(created)` function like this to make it work. `let totalSeconds = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - new Date(created).getTime()) / 1000);` I was getting created.getTime is not a function error though it was printing a date timestamp value only in the log for the created variable. Not sure of the reason behind it.

Comment: Also am a newbie to Angular so couldn't properly build this myself but now i understand it much better and learning too!!. Thanks again

Comment: any idea how it can be implemented if instead of date, seconds are entry?

Comment: @Srdan The conversion of seconds to hours, minutes, seconds is fairly simple maths. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nokits Is this your question?

Comment: I'm trying to implement your code like this
let totalSeconds = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - entry) / 1000);
where entry is equivalent to 10177 and it's updating every 0.2 to 3 sec
and that seconds are some soccer match  start so I need to display elapsed time from that seconds

Comment: @Srdan If you provide an example as a link I can take a look. It's not really good to go off on tangents like this in the comment chain of an answered question.

Comment: sorry, you are right
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kufxir-edit-iajkna

Comment: @Srdan I don't really get what your problem is. What's not working?

Comment: seconds come in dynamically (and they are different)  and when they do, minutes become same as first entry with couple seconds apart

Comment: @Srdan so `entry.created` refers to how many seconds ago an entry was created?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with RxJS like this:

```
  const startDate = new Date('2020-03-08 14:12:23');

  timer(1000, 1000)
    .pipe(
      map((x: number) => {
        const newDate = new Date(startDate.getTime());
        newDate.setSeconds(newDate.getSeconds() + x);
        return newDate;
      })
    )
    .subscribe(t => this.myDate = t);
```

Then in your component you do:

```
<div>{{ mydate | date: "hh 'h' mm 'm' ss 's'" }}</div>
```